# How does switch know which switch to send data?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, switch

For example

```
                  SW1
             /    |      \
         server1  SW2    SW3
                  |      |     \
             server2   server3 server4
```

If server3 send data to server4, `SW3` knows both MAC, so its just forward the data.

But what if server1 send data to server4? How does `SW1` know which port to  use to forward data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the MAC address. Switches do forward all ARP requests and build a database which MAC address is available on which port. As switches are transparent, this means direct or indirect through other switches. Unless you enable higher protocols. SW3 does not even know SW1 or SW2 exist.

SW3 knows the MAC addresses of all servers and which ot it's own ports to use for them. Simple like that. If you bothe reading the specs of any switch, there is always a notion how large this database can be - mostly is is in the more than 1000 entries range for anything not extremely cheap.